# Problem with building go proyect in docker (Build in Alpine and execute in Oracle Linux)

Tags: docker, go, alpine-linux, instantclient, oraclelinux

I have a problem building go proyect, I build with golang:alpine and copy the result to oraclelinux:7-slim the problem is when I execute the docker image the result is a error

```
"standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"".
```

I tried build with other base image by example "FROM golang:1.14 as builder" and  execute in oraclelinux:7-slim and the result is satisfactory.

I need execute in oraclelinux:7-slim because a need use Oracle Instant client to connect with database.

I would like build with Alpine because the golang:1.14 is very heavy.

Attached the dockerfile

```
# Start from golang base image
FROM golang:alpine as builder

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git && \
    apk add build-base

# Set the current working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and the go.sum files are not changed 
RUN go mod download 

# Copy the source from the current directory to the working Directory inside the container 
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .

# Start a new stage from scratch
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim

ARG release=19
ARG update=6

# Install instant client
RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y install oracle-release-el7 && yum-config-manager --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient && \
    yum -y install oracle-instantclient${release}.${update}-basiclite && \    
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

# Copy the Pre-built binary file from the previous stage
WORKDIR /root/

COPY --from=builder /app/main .
COPY --from=builder /app/.env .

# Expose port 8080 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8080

#Command to run the executable
ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]
```

Comment: You will have to look at the type of image the oracle version is using, It looks like the GOARCH and GOOS are incorrect for the given version (ie: The executable which you build will just not work in the Oracle image). Work around could be:
Use the oracle image to build instead of the alpine image, copy then from oracle image A to oracle image B to loose the go installation files. While you do have that oracle image with go installed: echo GOOS and GOARCH to see what it should have been (if it is the issue)

Comment: Checking to see whether there are missing shared libraries (`ldd ./main` in the target image) would also be a good next step.

Comment: Thank you Norbert but the oracle-linux don't have golang so I'll need install go with yum and configure gopath and others, i think that isn't a good idea.  But I'll try to delete GOOS and GOARCH maybe is the problem.

Comment: Oracle Linux yum server has golang: http://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-golang.html

Comment: thanks I resolved it with your help, build in oracle linux with golang and target the same oracle linux only with main.